# I intend to write some text file in both windows and Unix (Ubuntu) but when i save it the file sizes are different, why is that so?

Tags: linux, windows

I intend to write the following text file in both windows and Unix (Ubuntu):

Today is Wednesday.
Tomorrow is Thursday.
End of File.

When I save it on Windows it is 56 bytes long. On Ubuntu it is 54 bytes long. Explain
the difference please.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, windows uses both `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (line feed) to indicate end of line, while Linux uses only `\n`. This could explain a difference, depending on how many newlines you had, and possibly the encoding of the file.

Comment: On a modern MAC computer how long would the same file be???

Comment: Mac is based in Linux, but I don't know if that means it uses 1 byte line endings or not. Most modern systems will handle each other's newlines - maybe you should just pick one standard and convert your files to that or make a helper that counts size differently based on current platform. It sounds like known the file size is critical to you, and you might run into trouble if you try to predict what newline characters will exist in a file.

Answer (score 0):

In windows each line ends with "carriage return,line feed",
In unix and modern Mac lines end with "line feed",
In early Mac lines (before Mac OS X) Mac lines ended with "carriage return".